# OpenCV Face Recognition in Python

Tags: python, opencv

As seen in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html) link, face recognition is available in C++ with a number of different algorithms. However, when I try to create a recognizer in Python with something like `recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`, it doesn't seem to exist. Does the face recognizer module exist in Python, and if so, how can I use it? Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes? :-(

Comment: take a look at [this page](http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html)

Comment: there's also the the indico API which has python integration: https://www.indico.io/docs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anybody is still having this problem, the trick is to use opencv2 rather than opencv3. This is because in the new version, the face modules have been moved to opencv-contrib. You can compile opencv3 with that if you like but I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my complete code for face recognition using python. You also have to do one thing that in the directory where there will be your python file, you also have to put the training images. Also install the face recognition module.

```
import numpy as np
import face_recognition as fr
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

image = fr.load_image_file("me.jpg")
image_encoding = fr.face_encodings(image)[0]

known_face_encodings = [image_encoding]
known_face_names = ["Me"]

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    face_locations = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        matches = fr.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        name = "Random Person"

        face_distances = fr.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)

        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
    
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left+6, bottom-6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("Face Recognition", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```